# JSON is undefined in IE7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-7

It works fine in chrome, firefox and IE8. But comes up an error on IE7. Here is my jquery onchange event.

```
$('select#NationId').change(function () {
        var nationId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'LoadAreas',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ nationId: nationId }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('select#AreaId').get(0).options.length = 0;
                $('select#AreaId').append('<option value="0">Select All</option>');
                $.each(data, function (val, Areas) {
                    $('select#AreaId').append('<option value="' + Areas.Id + '">' + Areas.Name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadAreas(int nationId)
    {
        var _Areas = (from c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups
                      join cgt in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroupTypes on c.ChannelGroupTypeId equals cgt.ChannelGroupTypeId
                      where cgt.Name == "Area" && c.ParentChannelGroupId == nationId
                      select new AreaName() { Id = c.ChannelGroupId, Name = c.Name }).OrderBy(m => m.Name);

        if (_Areas == null)
            return Json(null);
        List<AreaName> managers = (List<AreaName>)_Areas.ToList();

        return Json(managers);
    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue is that [the JSON object is not available in IE 7.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503175/json-on-ie6-ie7/2503196#2503196)  You'll want to include [JSON2.j](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)s on your page for IE < 8 users.

Comment: i tried <script src="json.org/json2.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>. The onchange event does not get fired.

Comment: First, I'm assuming you are *not* actually hotlinking to JSON2 ;-)  Second, is the *event* not firing at all?  (And is this only in IE7?)

Comment: I copied the script that was in json2.js file, added that to my project and referenced that file on my master page. Thats all i did.<script src="~/Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @bladerunner - if you `alert(nationId);` in your `.change` handler, nothing is alerted? Or do you get errors? (And if so, what errors?)

Comment: Sorry i was gone on PTO. This was fixed. Copied json2.js file and included that in my master page. Tested in IE7 and the onchange event started working.

Comment: @SeanVieira i am getting the same problem that's why i have added the json2.js file in html but now t's giving me the erro "Object doesn't support property or method 'exec'" in my "jquery-1.11.1.min.js" file any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

If the browser doesn't implement the JSON object, you can always use [a third-party library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to provide it for you. If I recall correctly, this particular implementation is widely used and defers to the browser, so you just need to drop it in, no tweaking required.

Comment: Hi Kyte, So i copied json2.js in my project and referenced that file in my script header. The dropdown does not work at all.

Comment: @bladerunner: That's because [IE7 doesn't handle change() properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
data: { "nationId": nationId },
```

just work?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#NationId').change(function () {
    var nationId = $(this).val();
    var data = '{"nationId": "' + nationId + '"}';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'LoadAreas',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data ,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('select#AreaId').get(0).options.length = 0;
            $('select#AreaId').append('<option value="0">Select All</option>');
            $.each(data, function (val, Areas) {
                $('select#AreaId').append('<option value="' + Areas.Id + '">' + Areas.Name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```