# JSON is undefined in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

In ASP.NET MVC 3, I am using JSON in my AJAX calls. when i am running my application using visual studio on my development machine application works fine.
But If i Publish the same application and try to access it using Virtual Directory i am getting the error **JSON is Undefined**.

Code

```
function PopulateData() {

            $.ajax({ url: '../Home/Populate/',//**Error Line**
                type: 'POST',
                    data:  JSON.stringify({
                    'id':@ViewBag.Id                     }),

                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) 
                {         
                    //code

                } // ajax callback

            });  // ajax call

        }
```

Please Reply

Comment: did you add json ui files or any necessary document?

Comment: What browsers are you using?

Comment: What browser are you using to view your sites?

Comment: If you are using the server browser or the browsing capability built into IIS manager (I'm not sure what you mean here by *using Virtual Directory*) than it is an very old IE engine and it does not have built in JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is physical path in this line

```
url: '../Home/Populate/'
```

change it to relative path like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Populate", "Home")'
```

Also, you can see your json url with devTools of browsers. And, check it , if your json url is correct.

Comment: Hi AliRıza Adıyahşi  Tried using the relative path url: '@Url.Action("Populate","Home")',
But still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have given the url of controller which is local to the project.

It's always better to follow `@Url.Action("actionname","controllername")` this approach.

```
         $.ajax({ 
            url: '@Url.Action("Populate","Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data:  JSON.stringify({id:@ViewBag.Id}),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) 
            {         
                //code

            } // ajax callback

        });  // ajax call
```

Comment: Hi Karthik, Tried using the relative path url: '@Url.Action("Populate","Home")', But still getting the same error

Comment: @user1799982 what is the browser that you are using

Comment: @user1799982 [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503175/json-on-ie6-ie7) if you are using IE < 8

Comment: Hi Karthik My browser is IE 8 I tried removing JSON.Stringify then data is not fetched.

Comment: @user1799982 So, data option in $.ajax is `data: ({ id: @ViewBag.Id })`. Is it the same ?

Comment: @Karthik Take a look at `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. Because of that, data should be passed as JSON string.

Comment: @user1799982 Also what are you returning from `Populate` action method.Is it `return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` or `return View(data);` ?

Comment: Hi Karthik, FAngel..No luck yet.. m leaving for the day..Will again look into it on monday..Thanks Bye and Have a nice weekend..

Answer (score 1):

**JSON is Undefined** looks more like browser error. There is no built in  `JSON` in old browsers like IE7, FF3.0 etc. So, it looks like you are using different browsers to view your website. 
Suppose if you remove `JSON.stringify` it will work fine (not sure why do you need that at all, jquery accepts data as an object and will do everything required to pass it to server correctly):

```
function PopulateData() {

            $.ajax({ url: '../Home/Populate/',//**Error Line**
                type: 'POST',
                    data:  {'id':@ViewBag.Id },    
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) 
                {         
                    //code

                } // ajax callback

            });  // ajax call

        }
```

And as it was told in other answers here, you should better use `url: @Url.Action("Populate", "Home")` instead of relative url like you have it now

Comment: Oh. I see, you are passing it as json. Are you sure you can't use default application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: @user1799982 try to remove `JSON.stringify` and `contentType:...`. Possibly it will work fine, but that depends on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Because JSON is not built in all browsers download it https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and include in you  on your website

By the way why you are using stringify for primitive types?

you can do

```
 data:  { id: @ViewBag.Id }
```

Then on ASp.Net Mvc Controller side

```
public ActionResult Populate(int id)
```

So ASp.net will parse your parameter for you.

Comment: Thanks all..I Refered the link http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/