# knockout js ko.toJSON not working in IE7

Tags: knockout.js

Is this a knockout bug?

```
<h2>Debugging Variables</h2>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)">
</div>
```

I get the following error when viewing my page in compatability mode:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings. Message:
>   [object Error]; Bindings value: text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)

Works fine when compatability mode is off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ko.toJSON` uses the `JSON.stringify` method internally which is [**not implemented in IE7**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503175/json-on-ie6-ie7).

So if you want to support IE7 you need to include a `JSON.stringify` implementation like

Douglas Crockford's [JSON2 parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (you need the `json2.js` file)

Comment: Ah thanks, I now remember seeing that in the documentation :)