# IE7 Ajax out of memory error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

The script I am working on makes ajax call and it works fine on Firefox, chrome and IE8+. But on IE7, I am getting an out of memory error. The memory gets up to 120MB. I am using jQuery 1.8.3. The error also happens in jQuery 1.9 and 1.7.

the source:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'data.asmx/GetChildren',
    data: '{parent:"program","child":"office","id":' + this.Item_id + '}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (r) {
        var data = r.d.data;
    }
});
```

this is the profile i get for IE7:

[image]

edit: updated with source
edit: finally had time to go through the problem again. turned out to be a simple looping problem. not jQuery ajax's fault.

Comment: So, where's the code?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: This error is pretty self explanatory. IE7 runs out of memory. How big is data?

Comment: it's not big, at most 10 KB

Comment: is this code in some kind of loop / recursive function ?

Comment: not really, i found out it only takes one ajax call in ie 7 to get the out of memory error

Comment: Post more code, like the function that `$.ajax` is nested in. I doubt it's the causer. Something is missing

Comment: Does the `success` function run on any browser? If so, could you post the response data?

Comment: everything runs fine on every browser except ie7

Comment: might be an issue with deserializing the json. You may try replacing the ajax call with a script that just deserializes the corresponding json string and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: have you tried making a raw ajax call (without jQuery?)

Comment: Is it a must to run on IE7? If not I wouldn't bother...

Comment: I doubt it's related, but you can use an actual object literal for the `data` property instead of the string.

Comment: Could be IE7 bug. Does MS most recent patch fix it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms13-021

Comment: finally had time to go through the problem again. turned out to be a simple looping problem. not jQuery ajax's fault.

Answer (score 1):

IF number of children are more, then the value returned to the `var data` will be more.

The maximum length of JSON strings. The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data. [source Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx)

So size is not an issue, but the character if exceeds then it is a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it has something to do with your problem, but there are two things making your data an invalid JSON.

`parent` must be enclosed in quotation marks, just as the `id` value (you are only closing and reopening the string).

So, it should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'data.asmx/GetChildren',
        data: '{"parent":"program","child":"office","id":"' + this.Item_id + '"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            var data = r.d.data;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if virtual memory has been disabled.
To enable virtual memory, follow these steps:

Click the Start button, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
Double-click the System icon.
On the Performance tab, click Virtual Memory.
Click the "Let Windows manage my virtual memory settings (recommended)" option. Or, if you must use your own virtual memory settings, allow as much space as possible for the maximum size.
Click OK.

Comment: i don't think this is it. this seems like a jQuery + IE 7 bug. I can't tell my users to enable virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery docs you can pass plain object so I would suggest to use object instead. Also can you please try to use Id like this and see if it makes any difference.

```
var id = this.Item_id; //
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'data.asmx/GetChildren',
    data: {"parent":"program","child":"office","id": id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (r) 
    {
        //Please use console.log(r) and see what is coming back here
    }
});
```

or simply

```
var id = this.Item_id; //
$.post("data.asmx/GetChildren", 
{
    "parent":"program",
    "child":"office",
    "id": id
}, function(r)
{
    //console.log(r);
},"json");
```

Comment: IE7 does not support console.log function

Comment: I am aware that IE7 does not have console.log but please try this in Firefox or something just to check what's coming back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to send a JSON.stringify instead of an Object, and in the server side decode?

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
```

Comment: IE7 doesn't have native JSON support. You'll need to use JSON.js - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: you can add the fix in IE7 and will work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503175/json-on-ie6-ie7

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'data.asmx/GetChildren',
    data: '{parent:"program","child":"office","id":' + this.Item_id + '}',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (r) {
        var data = (eval("[" + r + "]")[0]).d.data;
    }
});
```

- Changed dataType to "text".
- Used eval("[" + textJson + "]")[0] to get the object data.
- - If it still fails replace the "var data = ..." line with "var data = r;" and report if that fails also.